# Porque meu AWS Elastic Balance Loader rejeita conexões SSL?

Tags: amazon-aws, ssl, dns

Recentemente, comecei a entrar no tópico segurança, mais especificamente SSL (HTTPS). Pesquisando no Google, observei que a Amazon Web Services (AWS) oferece gratuitamente certificados SSL para EC2 Load Balancers.

Entretanto, gastei um dia inteiro tentando realizar o setup e seguindo os tutoriais oficiais e não oficiais, nada deu certo.

Eu tenho um domínio registrado na GoDaddy, vamos assumir www.meudominio.com. Meu website é hospedado  na Amazon Web Services (AWS). Eu tenho acesso para editar tanto os registros de DNS  como qualquer configuração da AWS . Eu li um pouco sobre o LetsEncrypt, outra versão gratuita de SSL, mas o meu website é ASP.NET (C#) e roda em IIS Windows, não Linux.

Com tudo isso em mente, segue abaixo o que tentei fazer:

1. Obter certificado SSL do AWS Certificate Manager

Eu escolhi a opção de verificar via DNS, o que significa que eu adcionei um registro CNAME na GoDaddy.

[image: Página AWS Certificate Manager]

[image: Página Registros de Domínio Go Daddy]

Se você observar atentamente nas imagens acima, os valores do registro CNAME estão no centro da página AWS. Esses valores foram adcionados na GoDaddy.

2. Editar Load Balancer Listeners:

[image: Load Balancer Listeners]

3. Editar Security Groups

[image: Load Balancer e Instance Security Groups]

**NOTA:** Tanto o Inbound como o Outbund foram configurados com as informações acima. Eu também defini estes grupos tanto para o Load Balancer como para a minha instância.

4. Editar Route 53 Hosted Zones

[image: Route 53 Hosted Zone]

O registro tipo A type aponta para o IP da minha instância.

O registro NS foi gerado pela Amazon (Eu adcionei os name servers da GoDaddy's também).

O registro SOA foi gerado pela Amazon e não foi modificado.

O CNAME foi adcionado por mim. Novamente, contém os valores do certificado SSL.

5. CURL Test

O teste com CURL retorna:
"Failed to connect to www.website.com port 443: Connection timed out."

Eu não sei onde errei, ou porque não esta funcionando.
Qualquer ajuda é bem vinda!
Agradeço a sua atenção.

Comment: Em qual step você associou o certificado ao seu load balancer? Durante a criação do load balancer existe o step "Configure Security Settings" onde você pode selecionar o certificado criado no ACM.

Comment: No step 2. Pela imagem, é possível ver que há um certificado de SSL associado ao Load Balancer

Comment: vish, não tinha visto na img, que bom que deu certo!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finalmente, encontrei a solução para o problema.

### O contexto em que eu estava:

**Host**: AWS , **Provedor de Domínio**: Externo (GoDaddy)

Instância no Elastic Beanstalk rodando site ASP.NET conectada com o Load Balancer.

SSL selecionado para ser utilizado no Listener do Load Balancer.

HTTP 80   - HTTP 80

HTTPS 443 - HTTP 80

Políticas de segurança tanto do Load Balancer como do Elastic Beanstalk habilitando a porta 443 (HTTPS).

Certificado SSL obtido pela própria AWS através do Certification Manager. Na página do mesmo, o certificado se encontrava "Issued" e "In Use", ou seja, em uso e certificado pela Amazon.

No domínio de provedor (GoDaddy), o CNAME do SSL da Amazon estava registrado.

### A solução:

Apaguei o registro tipo A que apontava para um IP. O IP em questão era da instância do Elastic Beanstalk, que por padrão não conecta via HTTPS com o Load Balancer.

Adicionei um novo registro CNAME, mas desta vez apontando para o Load Balancer. 
Você pode encontrar o link do Load Balancer em EC2 > Load Balancer. Abaixo da tela, há uma opção "DNS NAME".

Após alguns minutos, o site deve funcionar forçando https://www.meusite.com

### Problemas Adicionais:

Neste momento, o meu website só carregava com SSL ao forçar https. Para resolver isso, a Amazon tem um tutorial excelente:

[Redirecionando HTTP para HTTPS](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/redirect-http-https-elb/)

Answer (score 0):

Como a mensagem indica que não conseguiu conectar, nem é um erro de ssl, mas aparentemente a instância não está respondendo na porta 80. Pode ser que o seriço não esteja rodando, ou sendo bloqueado pelo firewall do sistema operacional. Provavelmente você vai ver que a instância, se estiver cadastrada no load balancer, não estará com o status "In Service". Para mais detalhes, verifique os logs do load balancer.

Comment: Acho que você quis dizer que a instância não responde na porta 443, a padrão de SSL. Porém, como eu disse, tudo estava em funcionamento, menos acessar via HTTPS, e o site carregava em HTTP (porta 80).